# Datatables - force rendering after setting `bDeferRender: true`

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a table with 1000+ records and I am using `bDeferRender: true`.  I have a button that when clicked can select any of the records.  [Here is a jsfiddle showing the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/abell25/B8BT3/1/).  Here is the code:

```
the_data = [['1', '1', '1'], ['2', '2', '2'], ['3', '3', '3'], ['4', '4', '4'], ['5', '5', '5'], ['6', '6', '6'], ['7', '7', '7'], ['8', '8', '8'], ['9', '9', '9'], ['A', 'A', 'A'], ['B', 'B', 'B'], ['C', 'C', 'C'], ['D', 'D', 'D'], ['E', 'E', 'E'], ['F', 'F', 'F'], ['G', 'G', 'G'], ['H', 'H', 'H'], ['I', 'I', 'I'], ['J', 'J', 'J'], ['K', 'K', 'K'], ['L', 'L', 'L'], ['M', 'M', 'M'], ['N', 'N', 'N'], ['O', 'O', 'O'], ['P', 'P', 'P']];
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var oTable = $('#the_table').dataTable({
            "aaData": the_data,  
            "bDeferRender": true,
            "aoColumns": [
                { "mData": "Year", "sTitle":"Year" },
                { "mData": "Month", "sTitle":"Month"},
                { "mData": "Savings", "sTitle":"Savings"  },
        ]
        });

        $('#btn1').on('click', function() { 
            //output: 10
            alert($('#the_table').dataTable().fnGetNodes().length);
            //how to do this??
            forceRender();
            //this should now output 25
            alert($('#the_table').dataTable().fnGetNodes().length);
        });

    });
```

If i use `bDeferRender: false` then `$('#the_table').dataTable().fnGetNodes().length` will equal 25.  I want to defer rendering of the table, but when the button is clicked I want the table to actually ALL the records.

Comment: How is the button supposed to "select the last record"? Where do you define the `forceRender()` method? Maybe this [post](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/17630/force-deferrendering-to-false-after-datatables-has-been-rendered) can help.

Comment: This is a simplified example.  I am asking if there is a function that would force render (it's not implemented).  The button text is not important here.

Comment: Thanks @Raidri!  That post is describing the exact same problem!

Comment: OK, after you clarified your question I thought so too and posted / summarized it as an answer. Feel free to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per this [post](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/17630/force-deferrendering-to-false-after-datatables-has-been-rendered) in the DataTables forum there is no method to directly force rendering of all rows in the table. As workaround you can set the display length to show all rows (which will then render all rows) and then set it back.

```
var settings = table.fnSettings();
var oldDisplayLength = settings._iDisplayLength;
settings._iDisplayLength = -1;
table.fnDraw();
settings._iDisplayLength = oldDisplayLength;
table.fnDraw();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that it is better to use `fnGetData()` instead of `fnGetNodes()` since it will return all records.  I think `fnGetNodes()` is for operations specific to html tables (such as styling).